# if account type = x go to link 1 else if account type = y got to link 2?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

i have two types of users on my site, 'free' and 'premium'.
basically i have a messaging system that lists the message and the user who send the message.

when you click on the user's name/image it will link to `'profile.php?id=(user_id)'`

what i am trying to do, is if the account type of the user who sent the message = 'free' then i want to take the user to a different link when clicked on.

i am really new to php and am not sure what to do, please can someone show me an example of how i can do this. here's my current code.

function:

```
function message_account_type() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            global $profile_id;
            global $message_id;
            $query = "SELECT ptb_users.account_type, ptb_messages.from_user_id
                        FROM ptb_users, ptb_messages
                        WHERE ptb_messages.from_user_id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_messages.from_user_id ";
            $message_account_type = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($query, $connection);
            return $message_account_type;
        }
```

php:

```
<?php
$message_account_type = message_account_type();
while ($type = mysql_fetch_array($message_account_type)) 
if ($type['account_type'] == 'Premium')  {
echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$inbox['from_user_id']}\" ><img width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\" src=\"data/photos/{$inbox['from_user_id']}/_default.jpg\" /></a>";?></div><div class="message_text"><?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$inbox['from_user_id']}\">{$inbox['display_name']}</a>"; ?><? } ?>

<?php
$message_account_type = message_account_type();
while ($type = mysql_fetch_array($message_account_type)) 
if ($type['account_type'] == 'Free')  {
echo "<a href=\"members.php?id={$inbox['from_user_id']}\" ><img width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\" src=\"data/photos/{$inbox['from_user_id']}/_default.jpg\" /></a>";?></div><div class="message_text"><?php echo "<a href=\"members.php?id={$inbox['from_user_id']}\">{$inbox['display_name']}</a>"; ?><? } ?>
```

Comment: Side note: PHP is case-sensitive. 'Free' is not equal to 'free'

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to serve up the relevant template file inside of `profile.php`. For example, on your `profile.php` you could do something like this:

```
$the_user = new User($_REQUEST['id']);
$include_file = ($the_user->account_type == 'free') ? 'free' : 'premium';
include($include_file.'-profile.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I seriously have NO IDEA why so many of you open and close `<?php` tags within a document for no reason...

well a shorter version would be:

```
<?php
function is_premium_user($profile_id)
{
    $query = sprintf("SELECT ptb_users.account_type WHERE ptb_messages.from_user_id = '%s' AND account_type = 'Premium' LIMIT 1", $profile_id );
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        return false;
    return true;
}
$message_account_type = message_account_type();
while ($type = mysql_fetch_array($message_account_type)) 
if (is_premium_user($profile_id))
    echo '<a href="profile.php?id='.$inbox['from_user_id'].'><img width="50px" height="50px" src="data/photos/'.$inbox['from_user_id'].'/_default.jpg"/></a></div><div class="message_text"> <a href="profile.php?id='.$inbox['from_user_id'].'">'.$inbox['display_name'].'</a>'; 
else
    echo '<a href="members.php?id='.$inbox['from_user_id'].'><img width="50px" height="50px" src="data/photos/'.$inbox['from_user_id'].'/_default.jpg"/></a></div><div class="message_text"> <a href="members.php?id='.$inbox['from_user_id'].'">'.$inbox['display_name'].'</a>'; 
?>
```